# How to encrypt System.ServiceModel section of configuration file using command line tool?(WCF config file)

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, encryption, web-config

> I am using **aspnet_regiis -pef** command for encrypting the same but getting error. 
>   ***Error***: The configuration section system.ServiceModel was not found

Do i need to create separate section for service model and then encrypt?

```
<system.serviceModel>
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find the answer here:
[Encrypting app.config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349551/encrypting-app-config-file)

In short:

> The aspnet_regiis will only encrypt configuration sections - so you
>   need to selectively encrypt those parts you need, like this:

```
cd C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.serviceModel/bindings" .
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "system.serviceModel/services" .
```

etc.