# C# - winform - How to encrypt endpoint address in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WCF Encryption solution for App.config viewable to a client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855483/wcf-encryption-solution-for-app-config-viewable-to-a-client)

In my application, I use a webservice to authenticate member, I found out that .NET store endpoint address of the webservice in app.exe.config file. So I think it's very easy if someone can create another web service and change the configuation file, he can login to my app.

Please help,

Thanks

Now I'll implement something like this to source

```
this._dataService = new DataServiceSoapClient();
if (this._dataService.Endpoint.ListenUri.ToString() != "myURLofWebservice")
{
   //error
}
```

I think it solves my problem

Thank you all for your helps

Comment: Not worth it, it's still possible (and easy) to find out the address with external tools that monitor network connections and to channel it somewhere else

Comment: How are you authenticating the caller?

Comment: If he can reach the configuration file then this is only one of the many security risks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is also easy to use http sniffer to see, where application does requests, so encrypting endpoint address is also not a solution.
I think better way to do this, that webservice would sign request using private key and application would check signature using public key.
There are many examples of this, like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/02/21/how-to-sign-a-message-and-verify-a-message-signature-c.aspx